Flutter Change WebDataTable Color
I would like to change the background color of my WebDataTable but couldnt figure out a way how to do it.
Additionally I chose a WebDataTable cause i wanted to add a button inside of the table and this was the only possiblity to do it:
How to add buttons into datatables in flutter?
Is there maybe a better option?
My Code:
    [....]
            body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                  child: WebDataTable(
                      header: Text(
                        "Test-Table"
                        ),
                      ),
                      source: WebDataTableSource(
                        columns: [
                          WebDataColumn(
                            name: 'row_One',
                            label: const Text('row_One'),
                            dataCell: (value) {
                              return DataCell(value);
                            },
                          ),
                          WebDataColumn(
                            name: 'btn',
                            label: const Text('MyButton'),
                            dataCell: (value) {
                              return DataCell(value);
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                        rows: SampleData().data,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar());
  }
}


To change the background color of the WebDataTable, you can wrap it in a Container and use its color property, but unfortunately, WebDataTable doesn't directly support row or cell-level background color changes. A common workaround is to use Container widgets within DataCell to control the color of individual cells.
Regarding adding a button, WebDataTable does allow this with custom cells, but there’s also another flexible option: DataTable. It supports interactive widgets (like buttons) in each cell, and you can specify custom row and cell properties more easily.
Here’s a solution using DataTable with cell color customization and button support:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
              color: Colors.grey[200], // Table background color
              child: DataTable(
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Row One')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Button')),
                ],
                rows: [
                  DataRow(cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.blue[50], // Cell background color
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Text('Row 1 Data'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('Button clicked');
                        },
                        child: Text('Click Me'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                  // Add more rows as needed
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Key Points:

Container is used within DataCell to style each cell individually.
DataTable provides a flexible approach with simpler integration of buttons and interactive elements than WebDataTable. #datatable

